# dart content_shell does not run browser http-client request

Tags: testing, browser, dart, client

I have Linux Ubuntu 12.04LTS and I'm trying to make dart (sdk 1.17.1) test (0.12.13.+5) of such client-side code:

**test.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="application/dart" src="test.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    <script src="packages/test/dart.js"></script>
    <link rel="x-dart-test" href="test.dart">
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

**test.dart:**

```
@TestOn('browser')

import 'package:http/browser_client.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  test('client.get', () {
    var client = new BrowserClient();
    return client.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com')
    .then((result) {
      expect(result.statusCode, 200);
    });
  });
}
```

With

```
pub run test -p dartium test/test.dart
```

test passed OK and there is data exchange between test runner and remote server (firebaseio.com).
But with

```
pub run test -p content-shell test/test.dart
```

test failed by timeout and there is no any data exchange with remote server. Why? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Might be a version issue. Ensure you have a recent content-shell version installed.

Comment: Content_shell, dart-sdk and dartium are the latest (1.17.1), with other versions - 1.14.2, 1.15.0 - there is same situation. Package http (browser_client) is also fresh - 0.11.3+7. Will ask on github of package test.

Comment: You could try to replace the `rel="x-dart-test"` link with a normal Dart script tag and start `content_shell` manually (without `--dump-render-tree`) and load this test file from `pub serve` to see if you get any error message.

Comment: I don't know what to replace `rel="x-dart-test"` with. But using `pub serve` and `content_shell` started manually without `--dump-render-tree` the test passed OK.

Comment: `<script type="application/dart" src="my_test.dart">`

Comment: You might also need `<script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>`

Comment: Hmm... my `test.html` has `<script type="application/dart" src="test.dart">` and `<script src="packages/browser/dart.js">` already, isn't it? And `packages/test/dart.js` searches `<link rel="x-dart-test"` and doesn't work without it.